# my discord bot is cannot leave voice channel in other server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

i make a discord bot that can join and left voice channel. this is the code

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("you are not in a voice channel")
        return
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"joined {channel}")
    else:
        await ctx.vocie_client.move_to(channel)
        await ctx.send(f"moved to {channel}")
        
@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel.")
        return
    elif ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
        return
    elif ctx.voice_client.channel.guild != ctx.author.voice.channel.guild:
        await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel in this server.")
        return
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("Left the voice channel.")

client.run('token')
```

when i run it, it doesn;t have any problems, i test it on my test server it work normaly, but when i invite the bot to my other server it can join but cannot leave the voice channel, and then the same problem face me in my test server, the bot cannot leave the voice channel. if anyone know what is happening pls help me thx..

i try to change the code many times, for the first try the code is always works, the bot is works normaly, but when i try to do the same proces (try to make the bot join to another server's voice channel) the same problem is coming back, can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

First, the elif statement:

```py
elif ctx.voice_client.channel.guild != ctx.author.voice.channel.guild:
        await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel in this server.")
        return
```

it is meaningless since both sides will always equal because `ctx.voice_client` is a shortcut of `ctx.guild.voice_client`. It is the `voice_client` for your guild. So if it exists, it will always be the same with `ctx.author`'s guild when sending this command.
And if you cannot disconnect the bot from voice channel, you can try

```py
await ctx.voice_client.disconnect(force=True)
```

Comment: so apperently i found the problem my bot is cannot leave voice channel if the voice channel name contains emoji